# DataGridView : Master and Detail table in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, gridview, datagridview

How can i handle the selection of Master /Detail Grid in windows form. I want Details grid to show only the child records.

How can I do that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are binding to an object that contains a collection of child records as a property and you are using databinding:

```
List<MasterObject> MasterObjectList

MasterDataGridView.DataSource = MasterObjectList

DetailsDataGridView.DataSource = MasterDataGridView.DataSource

DetailsDataGridView.DataMember = "ChildCollection"
```

I think that is right, but not in front of a computer with VS installed to check it.  ChildCollection is the property on MasterObject that contains the child records.